# Executing Python script from webpage

Tags: python, html, postman, webserver, execute

is it possible to execute a Python script from a webpage? For example in local network, I have one computer (or Raspberry Pi microcomputer) acting as web server (Apache) that has Python running and webpage files. So when I visit that page from another computer in the same local network, I could upload a measurement CSV file (temperature time series) and automatically the Python script generates simple drawing from it?

I have heard about "Postman", but can this be used for what I want to do?